# Асинхронность. Почему не работает обработчик события?

Tags: c#

Господа программисты. Прошу вашей помощи. Разбираюсь с асинхронным программированием и иногда возникают некоторые сложности.  Вот есть такой класс:

```
delegate void simpleDelegate(int progress);
class Calculations  
{  
    public event simpleDelegate Progresschanged;  
    public int getsquare(int digit)  
    {  
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)  
           if (Progresschanged != null)  
                Progresschanged(i);  
        return digit * digit;  
    }  
}
```

и есть форма, где по нажатию кнопки запускается метод класса в асинхронном режиме:

```
delegate int myDel(int r);
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calculations calc = new Calculations();
        calc.Progresschanged += delegate(int r)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                progressBar1.Value = r;
            }));
        };

        myDel deleg = calc.getsquare;            
        IAsyncResult res = deleg.BeginInvoke(12, null, null);            
        int k = deleg.EndInvoke(res);
        listBox1.Items.Add(k);
    }
```

Не знаю почему, но приложение намертво зависает. Причём, если не использовать асинхронность, а сделать типа такого:

```
myDel deleg = calc.getsquare;            
deleg(12);
```

то всё работает. Что мне исправить, но не убирая асинхронности?

Comment: могу посоветовать **[AsyncFunc](http://asyncfunc.codeplex.com/)**, сам использовал, прекрасная библиотека

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понимаю, у вас присутствует взаимная блокировка. 
Вот что у вас происходит в главном потоке:

- Сначала вызывается `button1_Click()`
- Затем в этом методе создается новый поток для асинхронного выполнения `getsquare()`
- Далее сразу же вызывается `EndInvoke()`, тем самым блокируя главный поток до тех пор, пока не будет выполнен `getsquare()`

Теперь, что происходит в новом потоке:

- Запускается выполнение `getsquare()`
- Затем дергается событие, на которое был подписан делегат из метода `button1_Click()`
- Далее в этом делегате вызывается `Invoke()` сигнализируя диспетчеру потоков о том, что в главном потоке необходимо выполнить некоторое действие.
- Блокируется в освобождении главного потока.

Однако главный поток не будет освобожден никогда, поскольку заблокирован в `EndInvoke()`.
Решение проблемы: использовать Callback.

```
IAsyncResult res = deleg.BeginInvoke(12, new AsyncCallback(Complete), null);

// ...

void Complete(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var caller = (myDel) ((AsyncResult) ar).AsyncDelegate;
    int k = caller.EndInvoke(ar);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Новый поток не создаётся, всё кидаеться в текущий. Ну или мсдн и дебагер врут :-)

Comment: благодарю. Как раз callback и polling  являются следующей темой изучения

Comment: @Чад, да, был не прав. Однако, тем не менее делегат благополучно запускается. И потом зачем тогда было использовать `this.Invoke()`?

Comment: Да, естественно запускается, я это не отрицаю. Просто в том же потоке, я в своём ответе описал схему, просто не согласен с Вашей.

Comment: Хотя нет, все же я был прав. [Вызов метода BeginInvoke у запускает его в ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/2e08f6yc.aspx)

> Pass a delegate for a callback method to BeginInvoke. The method is executed on a ThreadPool thread when the asynchronous call completes. The callback method calls EndInvoke.

Так что мое поток все же создается и мое рассуждение было правильным.

Comment: я бы сказал, не создаётся, а используется уже заранее созданный, если говорить о ThreadPool

Comment: Да, но это уже детали. Важно то, что выполняется он в другом потоке со всеми вытекающими от сюда последствиями.

Comment: Сыплю голову пеплом. Попадает в другой тред, но до выхода из метода не запускается.

Comment: В том то и дело, что для **элемента управления**. Но здесь же BeginInvoke не у элемента управления вызывается, а у делегата :) Там по ссылке выше даже пример есть:

    IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(3000, out threadId, null, null);
    Console.WriteLine("Main thread {0} does some work.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    string returnValue = caller.EndInvoke(out threadId, result);
    Console.WriteLine("The call executed on thread {0}, with return value \"{1}\".", threadId, returnValue);

Comment: Я исправил ссылку, но принцип работы у них один. Он так же ищет поток с дескриптором, и выполняется в нём, а не создаёт новый.

Answer (score 2):

Ну у Вас тут нифига не асинхронность:

```
int k = deleg.EndInvoke(res);
```

Данный код будет ждать результата. И вешать поток нахрен.

И, кстате, вы понимаете что этот код будет выполняться в том же потоке, так же что тоже не будет в чистом виде "Асинхронно".
По факту, этим кодом(BeginInvoke) вы ставите в очередь на выполнение указанную функцию, если придут какие-либо другие события то они будут ждать завершения работы делегированного кода (будут в очереди за ним).

А зависание происходит от того что вы ставите в очередь на выполнения делегата, и ожидаете завершение его, а он не может даже запуститься т.к. вы не вышли из обработки кнопки.

Наверное вам лучше прочитать про **[Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)**'ы.

[Асинхронный вызов синхронных методов](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2e08f6yc)

Comment: У вас ссылки ведут на метод `Control.BeginInvoke()`, в то время как ТС вызывает одноименный метод делегата.

Comment: Да, исправился, спасибо.